# how does the index page know which app tag to load

Tags: angular

For index.html page I have an tag  and in my app.component.ts the selector is "app". In my component.ts the selector is also "app". How does angular 7 know which html page to choose and which app to choose since they 're the same name.

```
app.component.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'example';
}


component.ts:
  import { ApplicationRef, Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "template.html",
    styles: ["/deep/ div { border: 2px black solid;  font-style:italic }"]
})
export class ProductComponent {

}
```

Comment: It is not allowed to have multiple selectors with the same name, so it is nothing to decide for Angular :D

Comment: In the app-component.ts if I changed the selector from  
selector: 'app', to selector: 'app-1' I get the following error:,The selector "app-1" did not match any elements at DefaultDomRender2.push

Comment: It seemed somewhere it is pointing to the app-component.ts when I loaded the index.html page. Where is that set?

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't know. If you declare two different components with the same selector and you try to use them in the same module you will get an error. You might not notice an error straight away because the two conflicting components need to be used in the same module for Angular to start throwing errors.